# memory leak while using pvpython script

Tags: python, memory-leaks, vtk, paraview, pvpython

I wrote a script for `pvpython` to convert a batch of vtk-Files to binary vtu-Files.

```
import sys
from paraview.simple import *

print 'Number of files to be converted:', len(sys.argv) - 1    
for x in range(1, len(sys.argv)):        
    inputFile = str(sys.argv[x])
    outputFile = inputFile[:-1] + 'u'
    print x,': Converting ', inputFile, '  ->  ', outputFile
    r = LegacyVTKReader( FileNames= inputFile )
    w = XMLUnstructuredGridWriter()
    w.FileName = outputFile
    w.UpdatePipeline()
```

I run it like this inside a folder with around 2000 vtk-Files:

```
  pvpython conversion.py *.vtk
```

After some time, my systems runs out of memory.

Where does this leak come from?

I'm still new to python. Do I have to to delete the variables manually at the end of each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `Delete` call. e.g.

```
...
w.UpdatePipeline()
Delete(w)
Delete(r)
```